# Background color covers text in custom control Visual Studios

Tags: c#, custom-controls

I have been having an issue for a while. I created a custom control based on a textbox in Visual Studios. I am trying to get the background to change color based on the text in the custom control. I haven't even got that far yet. When I change the background color of the component it seems to be in the foreground and covers the text that is written in the custom control. The current code I have is

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles;

namespace ctlNumericTextBox
{

    public class AToDTextBox : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    {
        public int converterRange; 
        public float voltageRange;

        public int analogToDigitalValue; //Analogue Input Value
        public int maximumVoltage; //Max Allowed Voltage
        public float dynamicVoltage; //(analogToDigitalValue/converterRange) * maximumVoltage


        public Color controlColourGood = Color.Window;

        public Color controlColourBad = Color.Red;

        protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnTextChanged(e);
            //var displayValue = ADVAL
        }

        public AToDTextBox()
        {
            AToDTextBox customText = new AToDTextBox();
            customText.BackColor = controlColourGood;
        }
        public void SetRanges(int rangeForConversion, float rangeForVoltage)
        {
            converterRange = rangeForConversion;
            voltageRange = rangeForVoltage;
        }
        public void SetAtoDValue(int value)
        {
            analogToDigitalValue = value;
            dynamicVoltage = (analogToDigitalValue / converterRange) * maximumVoltage;
            this.Text = dynamicVoltage.ToString();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Creating an instance of yourselfs type in the constructor means an endless creation of that class. So you create a AToDTextBox that create a AToDTextBox that creates a AToDTextBox ad infinitum. You may be lucky in the designer as the thing you design isn't really created but at runtime this should end in a StackOverflow before seeing anything.  Just use the this pointer just like you used it for this.Text allready. Or leave it all away you are in the control so you can use the properties directly without referencing anything. So just use Text,BackColor etc. directly.